# Make a directory and change to it

Tags: bash, shell, unix

A basic shell function to [create a directory and change to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th/9124#9124) goes like this:

```
mkcd () { mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"; }
```

This works well in many cases but breaks in unusual cases (e.g. if the argument begins with `-`).

I'm writing a more sophisticated version. This version calls `mkdir -p` to create parent directories if needed and just change to the directory if it already exists. It has these design goals:

- Work in any POSIX compliant shell.
- Cope with any file name.
- If the shell has logical directory tracking, where `foo/..` is the current directory even if `foo` is a symbolic link to a directory, then the function must follow that logical tracking: it must act as if the `cd` builtin was called and magically created the target directory.
- If a directory is created, it is guaranteed that the function changes into it, as long as there is no race condition (another process moving a parent directory, changing relevant permissions, …).

Here is my best current effort. Does it meet the goals above? Are there situations where the behavior is surprising?

```bsh
mkcd () {
  case "$1" in
    */..|*/../) cd -- "$1";; # that doesn't make any sense unless the directory already exists
    /*/../*) (cd "${1%/../*}/.." && mkdir -p "./${1##*/../}") && cd -- "$1";;
    /*) mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1";;
    */../*) (cd "./${1%/../*}/.." && mkdir -p "./${1##*/../}") && cd "./$1";;
    ../*) (cd .. && mkdir -p "${1#.}") && cd "$1";;
    *) mkdir -p "./$1" && cd "./$1";;
  esac
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some error messages may be confusing like:

```
$ mkcd /foo/../bar
mkcd:cd:3: no such file or directory: /foo/..
$ mkcd /bin/../bar
mkdir: cannot create directory `./bar': Permission denied
```

Probably not much you can do about that.

Comment: I don't find the message from `cd` particularly bad: at least it's true. On the other hand the message from `mkdir` is wrong in that case. `mkdir … 2>&1 | sed …`? Or rather `error=$(mkdir 2>&1 …) || …` to keep the return status.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get away with handling only two error cases (empty or no parameter) and three path possibilities: Absolute path, relative path which starts with `./` and other ("dangerous") paths:

```
mkcd() {
    if [ -z "${1:-}" ]
    then
        printf '%s\n' 'Usage: mkcd PATH'
        return 2
    fi

    case "$1" in
        /*|./*) break;;
        *) set -- "./$1";;
    esac

    mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1"
}
```

You won't need the `--` separator. It might be surprising that `mkcd foo/../bar` would create *both* directories if they don't exist, but that's more to do with `mkdir` than the script.

Of course, this doesn't recursively simplify the path, which you'd need to do if you want to create the simplest absolute path defined (as printed by `readlink -f`, which is not in POSIX). But this would be surprising behavior, since `cd foo/../..` fails even when `../` exists.

Comment: If it was only a matter of the initial `-`, then `mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -- "$1"` would almost suffice (except for the oddball case of a [directory named `-`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53017/how-do-you-enter-a-directory-thats-name-is-only-a-minus/53021#53021)). The real complexity is in simulating the shell's logical directory tracking, when the argument contains `foo/..` where `foo` is a symlink.

Answer (score 0):

I try this command `mkcd --help` results in a new folder named `--help` and it cd to this folder, but if I try `mkdir --help` gives below output that I believe the correct behavior:

```
Usage: mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -m, --mode=MODE   set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
  -p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
  -v, --verbose     print a message for each created directory
  -Z                   set SELinux security context of each created directory
                         to the default type
      --context[=CTX]  like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the SELinux
                         or SMACK security context to CTX
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mkdir>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) mkdir invocation'
```

I can't remove `--help` folder after it created, `zsh-5.7`.